# how to access an array from a config.js file into a main.js file?

Tags: javascript

I have this array

```
var urls = {

};
```

in config file. How can i access this in my main.js file?

I tried normal method, making this array global in config file, but its not happening.

Comment: What order are you loading your js files in?

Comment: *"but its not happening"* What is not happening? That the object (it's not an array) is global? Please provide more context/information.

Comment: config.js has been loaded before main.js. But my question is, alright, let me show you my code, I have a url.js (config file) which has this array var urls = {chrome: 'www.googlechrome.com', Youtube: 'youtube.com'}; module.exports=urls; This is my config file. Now I have a main.fs file which has all the functions. My question is what methods should I use in main.js file to access urls array from urls.js config file.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `config.js` is loaded before `main.js` and you'll be fine, as long as you're declaring `urls` in the global scope.

Comment: config.js has been loaded before main.js. But my question is,

Comment: config.js has been loaded before main.js. But my question is, alright, let me show you my code, I have a url.js (config file) which has this array var urls = {chrome: 'www.googlechrome.com', Youtube: 'youtube.com'}; module.exports=urls; This is my config file. Now I have a main.fs file which has all the functions. My question is what methods should I use in main.js file to access urls array from urls.js config file.

Comment: You should be able to access `urls` directly. Is it `undefined`?

Comment: Am trying to optimize my code and make main.js file more efficient. I have close to 100 urls which i cant keep in main.js file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're exporting the config as a module — are you using RequireJS or another dependency library to load this? Some more context with the code would also be helpful.

edit:

I think the issue is that you're exporting only the urls in your config file. I'm not sure what your app structure looks like, but something like this is closer to what you're looking for:

```
// config.js
var config = {
    urls: {}
};
module.exports = config;

// main.js
var config = require('config');
var urls = config.urls;
```

Comment: I did that, I have nodejs included. But what kind of methods should i use, I was trying something like this in my main page. var url = url.urls.push; but am not able to get it.

Comment: Can you just use `urls.push`?

Comment: async.forEach(Object.keys(urls), function(x, callback). This is where i need to pull that array Elvis. Do you mean I should include, urls.push in Object.keys(??)?

Comment: I'm sorry, without more context I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script containing the relevant code is included into your html and it is included before you try to use that variable. Also, make sure that your variable is outside of any functions or accessible through a prototype.

Comment: Lajos: I have included in html. But my question is how can i access it? What methods has to be used, I tried this main.urls.push in my main page.

Comment: Your javascript is divided into multiple files. If you type var foo = 'bar'; in a file and you call console.log(foo); in another file, then it will either type 'bar' into your console or not find the foo variable, depending on the order in which you include your script files.